# Gnuplot animation of temperature along a bar during time

Tags: animation, matrix, plot, dataset, gnuplot

My dataset consists of a matrix of which the column number corresponds to 20 different positions along a thermally conductive bar and the first column contains the elapsed time of the experiment.

In other words, reading the row j of the matrix would give the following data in this order:
time t(j), temperature of position 1 at time t(j), temp. of pos. 2 at t(j), ... , temp. of pos.20 at t(j).

My goal is to produce an animated plot with positions along the x axis and displaying the relative temperatures on the y axis changing with time.

I'm a newbie in using gnuplot and any help would be much appreciated, the dataset can be modified if there is a shape that's easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data format is a little unusual, as all data for a frame seems to be in a single row. Here is a basic example that might get you started: imagine you have only 3 (instead of 20) positions, and a total of 3 rows (time points) in your data file:

```
0       2       4       6
1       3       4       5
2       4       4       4
```

The first column is time, columns 2-4 are temperatures. Then you can use the following script to loop over each row:

```
Npositions = 3
Nrows = 3

set xtics 1
set xlabel "Position"
set xrange [0.2:Npositions+0.8]

set ylabel "Temperature"
set yrange [0:10]

set boxwidth 0.5 absolute
set style fill solid

do for [row=0:Nrows-1] {
   plot for [column=2:Npositions+1] "test.dat" u (column-1):column every ::row::row w boxes notitle ls 1, \
    "" u (1):(9):("Time " . stringcolumn(1)) every ::row::row with labels notitle
   pause 0.5
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It works like a charm